# App with minSDKVersion=11 does not install on devices running on higher platform versions

Tags: android

My app has a `minSDKVersion=11`. This means that it can install and run on any device/emulator running on a platform with API version 11 or greater.

I have a Samsung Nexus S phone running Android 4.1.2 (Jelly_Bean API 16) and a GalaxyNexus emulator running on API 14.

My problem is that the app will install correctly on the GalaxyNexus emulator. When I try to install it on the NexusS phone, the Andrid Device Chooser does list the phone but does not allow me to select it

What could be the reason here?

Here is the attached screenshot [image: Screenshot of Android Device Chooser with OK button disables when NexusS is selected]

Comment: Did you grant the access to the phone?

Comment: When I connect the phone, it says that USB debugging is enabled. Inside `Developer Options`. `USB Debugging` is enabled.

Comment: Do you use eclipse or studio?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar you can see the eclipse logo in the pic

Comment: I use Eclipse platform.

Comment: Amit, enabling debugging doesn't necessarily mean that the pc is granted access to the device, you have to manually confirm that when plugging in the phone with the cable

Comment: @TimCastelijns my bad :)

Comment: Have you checked usb-debugging? If yes/no there is an option called revoke usb debugging authorization which will revoke access rights under Settings->developer options

Comment: After connecting there should be a popup where you need to grant access. I think this is what you are missing.

Comment: @TimCastelins `Developer Options` are enabled by default.

Comment: @ThomasR Since `USB Debugging ` is enabled by default, does it still need to show a pop-up?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://i.embed.ly/1/image?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iphone-android-recovery.com%2Fimages%2Fsmartphone-tips%2Fallow-usb-debugging.jpg&key=afea23f29e5a4f63bd166897e3dc72df

Comment: @ThomasR Ok. How do I enable this?

Comment: This should appear on your device when connecting the USB cable.

Comment: @ThomasR. Do I need anything specific on Linux?

Comment: You need to install the USB driver for your device. This can be found here: https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html